# nginx errors readv() and recv() failed

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I use nginx along with fastcgi. I see a lot of the following errors in the error logs

> readv() failed (104: Connection reset
>   by peer) while reading upstream and
>   recv() failed (104: Connection reset
>   by peer) while reading response header
>   from upstream

I don't see any problem using the application. Are these errors serious or how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was using php-fpm in the background and slow scripts were getting killed after a said timeout because it was configured that way. Thus, scripts taking longer than a specified time would get killed and nginx would report a recv or readv error as the connection is closed from the php-fpm engine/process.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to actually get a PHP error log or message out of this?

Comment: yes php-fpm-slow log. To enable this log you should configure php-fpm.conf

Answer (score 7):

### Update:

Since nginx version 1.15.3 you can fix this by setting the [**keepalive_requests**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive_requests) option of your upstream to the same number as your php-fpm's **pm.max_requests**:

```
upstream name {
    ...
    keepalive_requests number;
    ...
}
```

### Original answer:

If you are using nginx to connect to php-fpm, one possible cause can also be having nginx' **fastcgi_keep_conn** parameter set to **on** (especially if you have a low **pm.max_requests** setting in php-fpm):

```
http|server|location {
    ...
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    ...
}
```

This may cause the described error every time a child process of php-fpm restarts (due to **pm.max_requests** being reached) while nginx is still connected to it. To test this, set **pm.max_requests** to a really low number (like **1**) and see if you get even more of the above errors.

The fix is quite simple - just deactivate **fastcgi_keep_conn**:

```
fastcgi_keep_conn off;
```

Or remove the parameter completely (since the default value is **off**). This does mean your nginx will reconnect to php-fpm on every request, but the performance impact is negligible if you have both nginx and php-fpm on the same machine and connect via unix socket.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding this error:

> readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream and recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

there was 1 more case where I could still see this.
Quick set up overview:

- CentOS 5.5
- PHP with PHP-FPM 5.3.8 (compiled from scratch with some 3rd party
  modules)
- Nginx 1.0.5

After looking at the PHP-FPM error logs as well and enabling **catch_workers_output = yes** in the php-fpm pool config, I found the root cause in this case was actually the amfext module (PHP module for Flash).
There's [a known bug and fix for this module](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58679) that can be corrected by altering the amf.c file.

After fixing this PHP extension issue, the error above was no longer an issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very vague error as it can mean a few things. The key is to look at all possible logs and figure it out.
In my case, which is probably somewhat unique, I had a working nginx + php / fastcgi config. I wanted to compile a new updated version of PHP with PHP-FPM and I did so. The reason was that I was working on a live server that couldn't afford downtime. So I had to upgrade and move to PHP-FPM as seamlessly as possible.

Therefore I had 2 instances of PHP.

- 1 directly talking with fastcgi (PHP 5.3.4) - using TCP / 127.0.0.1:9000 (PHP 5.3.4)
- 1 configured with PHP-FPM - using Unix socket - unix:/dir/to/socket-fpm
  (PHP 5.3.8)

Once I started up PHP-FPM (PHP 5.3.8) on an nginx vhost using a socket connection instead of TCP I started getting this upstream error on any fastcgi page taking longer than x minutes whether they were using FPM or not. Typically it was pages doing large SELECTS in mysql that took ~2 min to load. Bad I know, but this is because of back end DB design.

What I did to fix it was add this in my vhost configuration:
**fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;**
Now this can be added in the nginx global fastcgi settings as well. It depends on your set up. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule

Answer (score 2):

Answer # 2.
Interestingly enough fastcgi_read_timeout 5m; fixed one vhost for me.
However I was still getting the error in another vhost, just by running phpinfo();
What fixed this for me was by copying over a default production php.ini file and adding the config I needed into it.
What I had was an old copy of my php.ini from the previous PHP install.
Once I put the default php.ini from 'shared' and just added in the extensions and config I needed, this solved my problem and no longer did I have nginx errors readv() and recv() failed.

I hope 1 of these 2 fixes helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Also it can be a very simple problem - there is an infinity cicle somewhere in your code, or an infinity trying to connect an external host on your page.

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned the **fastcgi_read_timeout** parameter, which is located in the nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    ...
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    ...
}
```

In addition to that, I also had to change the setting **request_terminate_timeout** in the file: /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
request_terminate_timeout = 0
```

Source of information (there are also a few other recommendations for changing php.ini parameters, which may be relevant in some cases): https://ma.ttias.be/nginx-and-php-fpm-upstream-timed-out-failed-110-connection-timed-out-or-reset-by-peer-while-reading/

Answer (score 1):

Some times this problem happen because of huge of requests. By default the `pm.max_requests` in php5-fpm maybe is 100 or below.

To solve it increase its value depend on the your site's requests, For example 500.

And after the you have to restart the  service

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I also checked /var/log/php8.1-fpm.log and found there:

```
WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

So I increased pm.max_children and additionally pm.max_requests:

```
pm.max_children = 50
pm.max_requests = 500
```

And that helped!