# PayPal API causes 502 on nginx/fpm

Tags: nginx, paypal, php

I'm developing PayPal Adaptive Payments on one of my sites. Problems comes, when i deployed app, to server with NGINX+PHP-FPM. When i'm trying to process paypal payment, nginx throws 502 error.

```
18777#0: *711 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /payment/5584 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com", referrer: "http://domain.com/process/5584"
```

PHP-FPM are using socket file, to communicate with nginx. All other apps on server, was running correctly. PHP has json, curl and openssl enabled.

Have someone similar problem with paypal? Maybe some tips, or what to look for, when configuring nginx/fpm for using paypal api?

**SOLVED**

Uncommenting one line in php-fpm pool conf, solved first problem:

```
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Then i saw next error:

```
Message Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1
```

Removing:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1'
```

From */sdk-core-php/lib/PPHttpConfig.php* solved this problem, and now, my payments are running correctly :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [nginx errors readv() and recv() failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733306/nginx-errors-readv-and-recv-failed)

Comment: Setting **catch_workers_output = yes** on pool conf, takes me to next error :)

Then, PHP throws TLSv1 error (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882530/paypal-sdk-adaptive-payments-unknown-cipher-in-list-tlsv1)

Changing this two things, solved our problem :)

Comment: You might also want to upgrade your PHP SDK... This cipher config was updated when the POODLE vulnerability was discovered several months ago.