# Running into a network error when trying to download large files with a Laravel and nginx setup

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, download

I simply try to download files in Laravel with

```
return Storage::disk($disk)->download($path);
```

which is working perfectly fine. But as soon as the size of the file exceeds approximately 1 GB the download stops and Chrome says "Network error".

I've insepected the nginx error.log and this is what I have found:

```
readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

I could not find any additional errors in Laravel log file or PHP FPM log file.

```
Laravel: 5.8
PHP: 7.3
nginx: 1.15.8
```

Is it necessary to apply any headers to the download response or do I need to tweak any php or nginx settings?

Comment: It's possible that the script is timing out before it has completed, or is using up too much memory when  reading in the large file.

Comment: Seems like a nginx configuration, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733306/nginx-errors-readv-and-recv-failed